# Jersey Rest service: 'Resource /Servers is not open'

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey, java-ee-7

I am new to Java EE and am trying to learn the same using tutorials and examples online.

I am trying to follow http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#first and create a RESTful service using Jersey.

Since this is my first RESTful service, I have basically copy-pasted whatever code is present till http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#first_run.

However, when I try to run the service, I am getting an error:

```
Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The Servers project is closed.
```

When I tried looking into the server configuration, I see that the configuration path is showing an error for the value: /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config.

When I try to change any (server) configuration and save it, I get the message: "Error while saving. Resource '/Servers' is not open."

Five differences between my project and what is described in the page:

1. I am using JDK 1.7, while the page mentions JDK1.6.
2. I am using Apache Tomcat Server 7.0, while the page mentions Tomcat version 6.0.
3. The Dynamic web module version is set to 3.0 in my project, while it is 2.5 in the page.
4. I have a couple of practise spring apps configured on my tomcat server. I am not sure how to remove them. :(
5. I have updated my web.xml to use `web-app_3_1.xsd` in the place of `web-app_2_5.xsd`.

I am not able to understand why this is happening.

If this does not seem to be solvable, I would be thankful, if you can point me to any resource that explains creating a RESTFul service using Jersey using Java EE7, Apache Tomcat 7 and, preferably, Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple. When I looked at the Project Explorer, I saw that there was a project called "Servers". Once I "opened" this project, the problem got resolved.

Seems like marking all projects and selecting "Close Project" has a side effect in Java EE Perspective. :)